# Need to avoid buffer overflow upon user entry over 8 chars above

Tags: c, if-statement, buffer, overflow

I am trying to restrict the amount of entered chars to 8, if more is
entered then the program should stop or display a msg and stop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int value = 5
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];
    strcpy(buffer_one, "one"); /* put "one" into buffer_one */
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two"); /* put "two" into buffer_two */
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one);
    printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
    printf("\n[STRNCMP] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]); /* copy first argument into buffer_two */
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two);
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
}
```

Comment: please update the formatting of your question

Comment: Please include your attempt - the code above doesn't contain any conditional statements.

Comment: the string functions always expect a NUL termination byte on the end of the string.  so, buffer_one needs to be [9] to allow for 8 char plus the NUL termination byte.  the printf statement says 'strncmp()' was used to copy argv[1] to buffer_two.  However the code actually uses strcpy()   suggest using: strncpy( buffer_two, argv[1], sizeof( buffer_two)-1 ); and char buffer_two[9] = {'\0'};  so the buffer is initialized to all NUL bytes.  To assist you, read the manual page for strncpy.  and/or <http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strncpy.php>

Comment: Interesting, I will try this in am. Tks you for your suggestion, I really appreciate it! Cheers! And tks for the comments info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is simply to check the length, and "abort" if it's too long:

```
if(strlen(argv[1]) > 7) {
    printf("Argument is too long.\n");
    return 1;
}
strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]); /* copy first argument into buffer_two */
```

(Note that an 8-char buffer only has space for 7 characters, plus the NUL terminator)